# How to pass gcc flags from goreleaser file, to link libraries

Tags: linux, go, build, libc, goreleaser

I'm running `goreleaser build -f goreleaser_build.yml`, on REHL linux. When setting no flag, the binary it builds has a few shared dynamic linked libraries:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff239f6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3a38370000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3a3816c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3a37f50000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f3a37d48000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3a3797a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3a38672000)
```

My goal is to link all them but libc statically. When running `go build` i assume it's like `go build -lpthread -lm` etc, but `goreleaser` does not accept such flags. There's a `ldflags` setting in goreleaser file, but I can't seem to set it to take effect.

My goreleaser file is almost like default:

```
builds:
  - binary: <name>
    main: cmd/<name>/main.go
    flags:
      - -mod=readonly
      - -tags={{.Env.TAGS}}
    ldflags:
      - -s -w -X main.version={{.Env.VERSION}} -X main.commit={{.ShortCommit}} -X main.date={{.Date}} -X main.host={{.Env.HOSTNAME}}
    gcflags:
      - all=-trimpath={{.Env.HOME}}/git
    asmflags:
      - all=-trimpath={{.Env.HOME}}/git
```

Also tried setting `export CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2 -lm"` but it has no effect. libm is still dynamic.

How can I set it via goreleaser file flags / go env vars, to make it link to those libraries statically? (i can't `-static` because I still need libc dynamic). Thank you!

Comment: I'm working on a Mac machine, so all those build process is run in a rhel container.